# What should we upload/push to Github repository when we are working with Electron?

Tags: github, electron, repo

I'm working with a Electron project, and now I want to push it to my Github repository, but I don't know what file I should push. Can any body tell me what file should I push?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can push any files you wish…

You will probably not want to push your IDE settings directory, perhaps unless you are the only person working on your application. Of course, when you make changes to any of your IDE settings, they will be reflected in your GIT status and require pushing as well if not ignored.

Most people **do not** push their `node_modules` folder due to the sheer size and frequency of updates it often receives. That said, there is talk that pushing your `node_modules` folder will prevent future issues should a package maintainer pull a package from NPM that you depend upon.

Lastly, I **do not** include my `build` or `dist` directories as these are quite large, contain binaries and are not really that useful until your final release, after which you will normally distribute it on a platform such as an app store, your own website or update server (or Github).

Comment: Shoud I push package.json and package-lock.json?

Comment: Definitely… Push `package.json` and `package-lock.json`.